# Expanding window with ugarchroll in rugarch in R

Tags: volatility, programming, garch

I was wondering whether my code is crafted correctly to satisfy this requirement:

- use 1:1000 to predict 1001, then use 1:1001 to predict 1002, and so on
- rOHLC has a length of 10079

```
e_spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model="eGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(0,0)))
e_mod = ugarchroll(e_spec, rOHLC, n.ahead=1, forecast.length = 9079, refit.every = 1, refit.window = "recursive")
```

Thank you very much for your help!